# How to fix or get around Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint

Tags: sql-server

I'm working on a c# program that goes thru SQL server 2012.  I want to build a history of a patient's status changes.  That is it has to be updated every time a patient cancels/changes any  healthcare provider.

I want to keep the history of these changes with a Primary key of their patient number.
My question is thus:  **Is there any way I can fix or get around the violation of the PK?**

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_patient_member_status'. Cannot
>   insert duplicate key in object
>   'dbo.member_patient_member_status_history'.

Comment: why you can't use `update` instead of `insert` ?

Comment: I want to keep ALL of the history of past healthcare providers etc.

Comment: then use another table for keeping details as @Habib suggested

Answer (score 2):

You can not enter a duplicate primary key instead **create a new table for Patient History**, with foreign key as the Paients' key. That table will have `1:M` (One to many relationship). You will be able to enter multiple history records or keep track of changes against a particular record.

```
That table will keep the changed fields for example:

Patient Table:

ID       NAME          Address
1        ABC             XYZ
2        DEF             PQR


Patient History 
ID       NAME          ADDRESS       FKPatientID
1        ABC            XYZ1           1
2        ABC2           YXZ2           1
```

In the above history table, it is keeping track of the changes against the main table. You can also keep record of `UpdatedAt` (DateTime) and `UpdatedBy`, (UserID)

Answer (score 0):

There can be only one record with a certain primary key. To fix, either loose the constraint, or broaden it, by adding more columns to the primary key.

A history log with a primary key on patient number sounds like invalid database design. History logs cannot really have primary keys, because you cannot find one column or combination that is bound to be unique. Use normal keys on the patient number or date of insertion.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you're trying to do is have an audit table of status changes. I would suggest that by design since a person can make multiple changes that you not make their patient number the primary key in this audit table..

You might consider having the separate audit table with the primary key as an Identity column (though you might want to keep and eye on the growth/number of records in extreme cases) or a UNIQUEIDENTIFIER column so the primary key is a GUID.

Since it would be important to get the status changes for a particular patient via querying, you might want to consider defining an [index](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189280.aspx) against the patient number in your audit/status change table.

HTH,
Nathan